# Angular2 - calculate time between two dates

Tags: date, angular

I want to calculate the time (in minutes) between two dates within the ngfor-loop in  the html of a angular 2 component. I found this for angular 1 but this does not work

```
{{ item.startdate | amDifference : item.enddate : 'minutes' }}
```

"The pipe 'amDifference' could not be found..."

Did the function changed?

Comment: is it angular 1 question or angular 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [angular2-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment) package. This package provides a lot of different pipes for date operation/manipulation.

Here is an example for the `amDifference` Pipe

```
@Component({
 selector: 'app',
 template: `
 Expiration: {{nextDay | amDifference: today :'days' : true}} days`
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast answer! I installed the module and try - but get the same error "zone.js:355 Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors: The pipe 'amDifference' could not be found". 
I use a html-template and make a ngfor-loop
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3" *ngFor="let item of _DataInterface; let i = index">

item contains startdate and enddate - I want to calculate and show the minutes between:

{{item.startdate | amDifference : item.enddate : 'minutes' :true }} Min

Comment: You have done all the steps of the installation? And have you import MomentModule into your app modules? https://github.com/urish/angular2-moment

Comment: Oh, I fotgot the part  'angular2-moment': {  in the systemjs.config.js:
I thought this works automaticly.Sorry. But now I get a new error:
zone.js:1274 GET http://localhost:14062/angular2-moment/index.js 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It seems to be a problem with typings. I got error if I use command "typings install --save moment".
typings WARN hastypings Typings for "moment" already exist in "node_mopt resolve the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by 
typings ERR! message Unable to find "moment" ("npm") in the registry.
typings ERR! message However, we found "moment" for 1 other source: "d
typings ERR! message You can install these using the "source" option.
typings ERR! message We could use your help adding these typings to th
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/moment/vers..

Comment: I tryed to update typings to 2.0, uninstall typings as suggested "You should let TypeScript resolve the packaged typings and uninstall the copy installed by Typings".

Comment: OK, i found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37777073/use-external-typescript-library-in-angular2-e-g-angular2-moment

And I copied the folder moment and angular2-moment to my wwwroot\lib (I use a web.api + angular combination and npm installed it to root of my core-webapplication -> node_modules.
Now I get no error anymore, but only ? instead of minutes but this seems to be a other error

Comment: Oh Yeah - restart of project and now it works! Thank you so much!